How do I make a sheet to document the time a task was started and ended and the duration (in decimal format)?
My employer has a sheet that we use to log our tasks.
Column "A" is the start time
Column "B" is the end time
Column "C" is the total time
Column "A" and "B" are in 24-hour format (0100, 0230, 1300, 1800, etc.)
Column C needs to be in decimal format (.25, .5, .75, 1.25, etc.)
Example, I start a task at 3am and end it at 330 am - total time 0.5 hours
A1 = 0300
B1 = 0330
C1 = 0.5

Any ideas how I can make this work?
I've tried to format column "A" and "B" using the custom date and time to show hours and minutes with a leading 0, but when I enter 0300, it changes to 300.

Try =(B1-A1)*24 in C1 cell.

"24-hour format (0100, 0230, 1300, 1800, etc.)" — that's not a 24-hour format. Those values look like integers with leading zeros. Times look like 01:00, 02:30, 13:00 and 18:00. Use proper duration values instead of "digital hours." See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

The source data format is unclear. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Converting minutes to decimal
Try entering data in the cell before applying a custom format for the 24-hour time. Also, input a valid time to achieve your desired outcome.
You can try this Formula:
=LET(result, SPLIT((B6-A6),":"), hrs, CHOOSECOLS(result,1), mins, CHOOSECOLS(result, 2), JOIN(".",hrs,(ROUND(mins/60,2)*100)))

Output:

You can also use the BYROW function with the formula above to apply it across your desired range. Since my range is A2:B6, that’s the range I specified.
=BYROW(A2:B6, LAMBDA(row, LET( result, SPLIT(INDEX(row, 2) - INDEX(row, 1), ":"), hrs, CHOOSECOLS(result, 1), mins, CHOOSECOLS(result, 2), JOIN(".", hrs, ROUND(mins/60,2)*100)) ))

Output:

Reference:
CHOOSECOLS
LET Function
Join
Byrow

You can get the same result more simply with =(B1 - A1) * 24. But it would be even simpler to use =B1 - A1 and format the formula cell as a duration. See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

I understand what you mean, and yes, that approach would indeed be easier. However, based on my understanding of the post, I think the original poster (OP) has an additional question about converting 00:30:00 to 0.50 or convert to a decimal point system based off the Hours taken+minutes taken/60 minutes.

"convert to a decimal point system based off the Hours taken+minutes taken/60 minutes" — my point is that your longish let() formula is just a convoluted way of saying =(B6 - A6) * 24. Format the cell as Format > Number > Number to see it as "digital hours." See the post I linked.
